# How to pass parameters in post deployment script from VSTS pipeline -C#

Tags: c#, azure-pipelines

I want to pass some value in my post-deployment script from my vsts Pipeline, How can I do that? what I have to write in a post-deployment script and what are the steps?

Comment: Are you looking to pass a pipeline variable to the post-deployment script? Assuming your script has variables and you want to assign those variables with pipeline variables.

Comment: @RajuDasupally yes

Comment: If you are trying to update your varibles in the post-deployment script with other variables in Azure DevOps, the [Logging Commands](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md#logging-commands) shall be what you are looking for. Try `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue"`. For more information, please check [Set variables in scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts).